# Lendo arquivo json via AngularJs service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-services

Estou tentando ler um arquivo Json via um service que eu criei:

Service:

```
App.factory('service', function($http) {
        var promise;

        get: function() {
            if (!promise) {
                promise = $http.get('../library/data_json.json')
                    .success(function (response) {
                        console.log('success');
                        promise.data = response;
                    });
            }
            return promise.data;
        }
    });
```

Declaração do controller

```
App.controller('CauController', function (service, $http, $scope) {
```

Agora no Controller eu chamo a função que vai me retornar o promise do $http;

```
service.get().then(function(data) {
     $scope.dados = data;
});
```

erro :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o erro;;

Eu estava declarando um factory como um service,
o mesmo deve ter a seguinte estrutura

```
module.factory('MyService', function() {

    var factory = {}; 

    factory.method1 = function() {
            //..
        }

    factory.method2 = function() {
            //..
        }

    return factory;

});
```

Comment: Marque sua resposta como "Aceita" para sinalizar que essa resposta resolveu o seu problema. =D

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar valor, segue um guia de respeito: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui 
e fornecer o link para referência. As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página 
com o link for alterada.